# in grails 3, with command objects, how do you NOT update say password field?

Tags: grails

If you have a service method save(User user) which simply calls user.save(), how do you stop it overwriting the password with a blank value (or failing validate if its null) if the user had say edited his address? the password is not sent to the update view.  In the old days, we used to have something like this:

```
def update(Map params) {
    params.remove("password")
    player.properties = params
    player.save()
}
```

Now we have this:

```
   interface IUserService {
      User get(Serializable id)
      List<User> list(Map args)
      Long count()
      void delete(Serializable id)
      User save(User user)
      User update(User user)
   }

@Service(User)
@Transactional
abstract class UserService implements IUserService {
    @Override
    User update(User user) {
        user.save() // this will overwrite the password, or fail if the password is null.
}
```

What is the new equivalent of params.remove?  How do we not update the password on updating of the object?  I guess we could read the current password out of the DB, and assign it to the passed in object before saving, but this is another read.  Or we could write some custom sql which updates each field but not the ones we want to mask?

Comment: this first bit looks like straight up params the 2nd is bound to physical user object and looks more like a typical rest interface.You are saving object directly so 1 way would be to save and assign user as well as some validation bean object that  doesn't contain password or builds a map that doesn't have password and it becomes `User save(User user, UserBean userBean)`  then 
`User update(User user, UserBean userBean) {
  user.properties=userBean.loadValues() //where this loads the map of the data you wish to save
           user.save()
     }`

Comment: But I wonder if this is a special situation and typically you would want everything saved only this case should it work different and to hack behaviour you could set your own 
setter for password  
`
void setPassword(String pass) {
//do nothing
}

void setRealPassword(String pass) {
this.password=pass
}
`
where your standard call to update password does nothing, you call special setRealPassword in object when you need to update password.

Comment: This isn't really what you asked but fyi... It isn't great practice to use domain classes as command objects because that results in database interactions happening in places where it probably shouldn't.  Better practice is to have all of your database interactions happening in a transactional service.  There are some contexts where it is ok to use domain classes as command objects but that is largely misunderstood and I kind of regret that we added support for doing that.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure properties to not participate in mass property binding using the `bindable` constraint.

```
class User {
    String username
    String password

    static constraints = {
        password bindable: false
    }
}
```

Now the data binder will exclude the `password` property during the data binding process and you get to decide when/if that property is updated.  You could do something like `per.password = params.password` (or similar) whenever you want to update the password.

Comment: that looks useful, thanks.  For create, I want to set a password, but I can use your params option.

Comment: Great.  I wrote about `bindable` shortly after introducing it.  See https://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails/.